# NIPT test results given results of combined test (in pregnancy screenings)

Tags: obstetrics, statistics, test-results, downs-syndrome

The NIPT test gives a probability of a baby having Down syndrome. Supposedly, this test is more accurate than the combined test.
However, I haven't seen any statistics regarding the accuracy of the NIPT test *given* the results of the combined test.

More precisely:

> Is there an available statistics of the probability for getting a high risk for Down syndrome in the NIPT test, given that the risk in the combined test was low?

Alternatively, is it known that these results are uncorrelated?